# html2canvas captures everything except the content of an inner canvas

Tags: javascript, leaflet, webgl, html2canvas

I've got a map rendered by means of `leaflet`.

I need to make a screenshot of that map by using `html2canvas`.

To make use of `html2canvas`, I need to provide a DOM element to capture (`elementToCapture`) and an optional configuration (`html2canvasConfiguration`).

```
var html2canvasConfiguration = {
    useCORS: true,
    width: map._size.x,
    height: map._size.y,
    backgroundColor: null,
    logging: true,
    imageTimeout: 0
};

var elementToCapture = map._container.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-pane leaflet-map-pane')[0];
html2canvas(elementToCapture, html2canvasConfiguration).then(function (canvas) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = 'test.png';
    link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    link.click();
    link.remove();
})
```

I extract an element by the `leaflet-pane leaflet-map-pane` class, which basically represents the whole map including controls (zoom in/out buttons, scale, etc), custom markers, tooltips, overlays, popups.

The entire DOM looks like

```
<div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-map-pane">
    <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tile-pane">
        <div class="leaflet-gl-layer mapboxgl-map">
            <div class="mapboxgl-canvas-container">
                <canvas class="mapboxgl-canvas leaflet-image-layer leaflet-zoom-animated"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="mapboxgl-control-container"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-shadow-pane"></div>
    <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-overlay-pane"></div>
    <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane"></div>
    <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tooltip-pane"></div>
    <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-popup-pane"></div>
<div class="leaflet-control-container"></div>
```

The problem I've faced is the `leaflet-pane leaflet-tile-pane` element (particularly the content of the inner `canvas`) doesn't get captured by `html2canvas`. To put it simply, I see everything *on* the map, but I don't see the map *itself*.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**

The version I am currently using is `1.0.0-rc.1` (the latest one).

**UPDATE 2:**

The nature of the canvas is `webgl`. Might it be the issue? According to [this](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1420), they do support `webgl` canvases.

**UPDATE 3:**

I tried to obtain the canvas programmatically and call `toDataURL` on it. It resulted in an empty screenshot, even with the `preserveDrawingBuffer` hack.

**UPDATE 4:**

Oddly enough, it doesn't capture only certain canvases. I've created a `2d` canvas (by adding `preferCanvas` to map configuration) and it got shown.

Comment: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1311 Could this be related? They added the option `removeContainer: false` to temporarily fix it.

Comment: The problem should be fixed in the newest release from 4/10/2019: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/tag/v1.0.0-rc.1

Comment: @TheBlackIPs Thank you. I just tried it, and it didn't change anything. I am using the latest version.

Comment: When do you call html2canvas? Are you sure the page has had time to render? Is there any way you could provide an example as a snippet?

Comment: @TheBlackIPs yes, I am sure. The code gets executed on a button click. The button is rendered on the map controls layer.

Comment: Can you provide the code that renders the leaflet map?

Comment: @TheBlackIPs I can't share the real code, but I'll simplify it and share a jsfiddle.

Comment: @TheBlackIPs I can't share a jsfiddle either, it doesn't show the map, because leaflet tries to load some resources over HTTP (not over HTTPS). But I can assure you it's a very straightforward initialization,  there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @TheBlackIPs I updated the question. html2canvas seems to not want to work with webgl-based canvases. Do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this, add this to the top of your page, before any other scripts

```
<script>
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function(origFn) {
  return function(type, attribs) {
    attribs = attribs || {};
    attribs.preserveDrawingBuffer = true;
    return origFn.call(this, type, attribs);
  };
}(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext);
</script>
```

Does it help?

Comment: I wanna kiss you :) Could you elaborate on why it works? Does it force `html2canvas` to set `preserveDrawingBuffer` every time it retrieves the canvas context?

Comment: You can not set canvas attributes after getting a context. They can only be set once at creation time

Comment: does it have to be embedded or is there any nicer/cleaner solution?

Comment: You can put it in a script and include it.

Comment: Nice one! I was stumped there

Comment: where can i add in vue cli

Comment: i want to use this in React using arrow functions, i should remove 'this' and what replace that with ?

Comment: Moving your comment to the answer could make your answer more complete, currently it's just a piece of code(helpful) without explanation(context) of what it does.

Comment: Still more people wanting to kiss you}!!